# Silverlight splash screen

Tags: wcf, silverlight, splash-screen

I have a SL app with WCF to which I would like to add a splash screen to display during the WCF call finishes. How would I go about doing this? Been googling without success. Currently my splash screen shows while the package is loading but the app shows while waiting for WCF.

Comment: how do you show your splash screen? I dont see this being a WCF question

Comment: yeah well it is. I want a splash screen to display whilst waiting for a WCF response which occurs when app is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the variant is to show ChildWindow during WCF call.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow(v=vs.95).aspx

Another: BusyIndicator from Silverlight Toolkit.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse_overview_topic4#_Toc259103645

Comment: thanks I think I will be able to achieve what I want with this :)